# SQL - trigger as log of update

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlite

My tables are:
-stormtrooper
-squad
-platoon

Stormtrooper has 'ID' as primary key and 'squadID' as foreign, squad has 'ID' as primary key and 'platoonID' as foreign and platoon has 'ID' as primary key.

Using trigger I want to display everything that connects to stormtrooper which I update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER UPDATE ON stormtrooper
```

But I don't know how to display in one trigger datas of stormtrooper, squad and platoon which includes this stormtrooper.

Comment: You really cannot "display" data in a trigger.  It is running on a server somewhere and may not have access to the user's machine.

Comment: I know, I know. I mean - use "SELECT * FROM STORMTROOPER WHERE id = NEW.id;" - this will "display" datas of updated stormtrooper. But how "display" datas of squad and platoon, which contains this stormtrooper?

Comment: You can get the record using a join.

Comment: I have problem with this. Could you write sample of code to my stormtrooper example? I would really appreciate.

Comment: Triggers aren't to `SELECT` data, they just update/validate/change/log/whatever on the affected data, but you can't simply get data out of them. Issue a separate `SELECT` statement after your `UPDATE`.

Comment: This is my task - "Create one table that act as log, using trigger"

Comment: So you would use the trigger to update the log, then after the insert, you would select from the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following steps i show you an example for your question.
So lets create the examples of your basic tables.

```
CREATE TABLE PLATOON (
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  name nvarchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE SQUAD (
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  name nvarchar(20),
  platoonId int,
  constraint fk_platoon foreign key(platoonId) references PLATOON(id)
);

CREATE TABLE STORMTROOPER (
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  rank nvarchar(20),
  squadId int,
  constraint fk_squad foreign key(squadId) references SQUAD(id)
);
```

You should create a table for logging by using trigger to log updates. So lets create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_TABLE
(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  logText nvarchar(200)
);
```

Now create a trigger for after update an entry of the table STORMTROOPER.

```
CREATE TRIGGER log ON STORMTROOPER
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE
  select 'updated stormstrooper ' + cast(d.id as nvarchar) + ' in ' + SQUAD.[name] + ' of ' + PLATOON.[name] + ' from rank ' + d.[rank] + ' to ' + i.[rank]
  from deleted d
  inner join inserted i on (i.ID = d.ID)
  inner join SQUAD on SQUAD.[id] = i.[squadId]
  inner join PLATOON on PLATOON.[id] = SQUAD.[platoonId]
END
```

That is an example for logging the update. The MS SQL has 2 tables for insert/update/delete. Insert uses Inserted and deleted uses Deleted. An update entry first is marked as Deleted and then insert (with new values) in Inserted. So you can compare the values of Inserted and Deleted to get your changes.
You can create more use cases for your specific requirements.

To read the log you just have to `SELECT * FROM LOG_TABLE`.
You find this example with some data at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c926cd/1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have some problem with this right now. I created trigger like this:
http://pastebin.com/ChzUF0q1
But now when I try update stormtrooper table, I have an error: "no such table: main.deleted". I know it's becouse of trigger, becouse I can easily change every other table.

Comment: It seems that you use sqlite. Sqlite don't know the tables deleted and inserted. Instead of that you can use direktly new and old. For example new.rank.